# Difficulty in defining HTML table

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to create the below table in HTML. It's very basic, I know, but I'm stuck at the header.

The year needs to span over all the months. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: `Task name` needs `rowspan=2` and the `2013` column needs `rowspan=4` (from what I can tell). Note as well that the second row with month names needs to be two columns less than the rest (see `Task name` and the empty space spanning two rows to the left of that column header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `colspan="12"` to the year cell and `rowspan="2"` to the Task name cell

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wgp7V/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td  rowspan="2">Task name</td>
        <td colspan="12">Year</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Task name</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>December</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Task name</td>
        <td colspan="12">Rest of cells...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: excellent. with rowspan="2" on the Task name header it works perfectly. Now ... how would you go about implementing a row in the table? Each month has 4 cells :(

Comment: Same principle. You just have a slightly more complicated structure so the values change: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgp7V/3/